# How to serialize exported type using typescript compiler api

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-compiler-api

Hi I'm trying to get information on exported object type, to serialize it further. I checked there was similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333171/typescript-compiler-api-extract-exported-typescript-object), and made the same example like that bellow:

```js
const ts = require('typescript');

const code = `

type Config = {
  hello: string;
};

const config: Config = {
  hello: "world",
};

export default config;
`;

const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile('myModule.ts', code, ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext);
const program = ts.createProgram([sourceFile.fileName], {});
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
const sourceFileSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(sourceFile);
const exp = typeChecker.getExportsOfModule(sourceFileSymbol);
```

But it throws me an error, because for some reason `sourceFileSymbol` is `undefined`

```bash
typescript.js:49454 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'flags')
    at getSymbolLinks (typescript.js:49454:24)
    at getExportsOfModule (typescript.js:51578:25)
    at Object.getExportsOfModuleAsArray [as getExportsOfModule] (typescript.js:51517:35)
    at <anonymous>:18:27
```

I wish Typescript compiler api docs to be better I couldn't find anything valuable and I'm a bit lost here. Possibly the api has changed. I'm using version **4.7.1**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the output of:

```
console.log(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program));
```

It's having trouble finding the source file:

```
File 'myModule.ts' not found.
```

Basically, the program being created is not using `sourceFile` and then searches for the `myModule.ts` on the file system. Getting it use an in-memory file system is a lot of setup and work with the compiler API. I'd recommend checking out something like [@ts-morph/bootstrap](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph/tree/latest/packages/bootstrap) to do that instead.

---

```
// example using file system
const program = ts.createProgram(["./myModule.ts"], {});
console.log(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program));
const typeChecker = program.getTypeChecker();
const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile("myModule.ts");
const sourceFileSymbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(sourceFile);
const exp = typeChecker.getExportsOfModule(sourceFileSymbol);
console.log(exp);
```

Comment: I created real module.ts, but got same error. I'm running code using `node --inspect`, and `console.log(ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program));` went into infinite loop. No it finished and printed empty array

Comment: @Firanolfind I added an example that uses the file system

Comment: Thank you @David Sherret, it gave me `[SymbolObject]`. For other researchers I'm continue using exp by that guide https://stackoverflow.com/a/72339607/1424460